# Ubuntu default terminal missing on 13.04

Tags: unity, compiz, gnome-terminal

There was a problem with my Unity on Ubuntu 13.04 install in which I could not see any icons after logging in. Just a blank screen.

Used `ccsm` to purge Unity, reinstalled it and reset the settings after which it worked fine. After these steps I noticed that the default Terminal icon is missing from the `DASH` home search. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key sequence also does not open the terminal(even though this keyboard shortcut is already in place).

I've reset `Unity` and `Compiz` and restarted my system, but the issue still persists.

Can't seem to find any solution in the forums. Can someone please help? Its annoying to use `Xterm` instead of the default Terminal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using your xterm write those commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

The password is your account password and those commands will reinstall gnome-terminal, which should be the "default" terminal.
I hope it will fix.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps to set gnome-terminal as default**

- Execute following command in terminal

  ```
  exo-preferred-applications
  ```
- **Preferred Applications** Window will open go to <kbd>Utilities</kbd> tab.
- Under **Terminal Emulator** chose `Gnome Terminal`.

  if `Gnome Terminal` not listed, install it by `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the window.

That's all..!  Reply if something goes wrong..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you removed Unity, you may be missing other desktop dependencies, or they may not be on their latest versions. To get everything installed again, open up Xterm and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` meta package, which depends on all the other components of the desktop (and was likely removed if you ran `apt-get purge unity`).

If you're still missing the default Terminal, then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```